# quantity in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

So I'm building an inventory system to teach myself rails and am having a dilemma when it comes to what to do when adding a new product.

Product (pair of Glasses)
-frame
-lens
-accent
-name
-picture

eg.. I want to add 50 pairs of glasses (or 50 products) all with the same frame/lens/accent/name/picture and associate a picture with the product.

My question is should I have the database create 50 separate entries (1 per each product) or should I create 1 product entry, with a "Quantity" attribute/column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a quantity column. There wouldn't be any benefit to repeating so much data, which is something you generally should avoid. It would make getting the count for a product more expensive.